# How to change the extent of a raster after converting its coordinates?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, coordinates, arcgis-9.3

I changed the coordinate system from Conical coordinates to lat/long UTM-39N. It's OK, but the new layer doesn't have appropriate extent, so it can't be plot on other layers.
I exported the raster file with "dataframe extent and spatial references", but it doesn't work. Also, I used define project and raster project tools. still doesn't work.
what should I do?

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: I am using arcGIS 9.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the source of error is in your first step -

> I changed the coordinate system from Conical coordinates to lat/long UTM-39N

From your question it is not obvious how did you do that. You cont simply change coordinate system, you must transform raster to new coordinate system.

The proper way will be by *Project Raster* tool and you must be sure that your input raster have a correct coordinate system. The same goes with output raster. You must be sure with this, because if your input raster has conical coordinates as defined projection, but it is in different coordinate system, the result transformation will be wrong, with probably completely different extent.

Note that you use *Define projection* tool only to define projection on raster, it does not change actual projection (or extent) it only associates raster with coordinate system. To change projection you need to run *Project Raster* tool with properly defined projection on input Raster.

Comment: My layer was river density. I tried to change the coordinate from the first step. So, I changed the coordinate system of the shape file. Now, It's OK. but the mentioned methods didn't work on raster layer. By the way, it's ok now. Thanks.